# Do I have to free memory manually when I use CreateSolidBrush as a parameter to SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND,

Tags: winapi

I'm making a lame imitation of an explosion by fluctuating the background color between red and orange.

Do I have to use DeleteObject or free the object somehow after using SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG) CreateSolidBrush( RGB(255, 0, 0) ) ) ?

```
void ExplosionVisuals(HWND hwnd)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG) CreateSolidBrush( RGB(255, 0, 0) ) ); // Red
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        Sleep(100);
        SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG) CreateSolidBrush( RGB(255, 153, 0) ) ); // Orange
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        Sleep(100);
    }

    SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH) );
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    return;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty awful.  Of course you do.  Implement a message handler for WM_ERASEBKGND instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code leaks brushes. If you really wish to create new brushes each time round the loop then you have to get the previous value (returned by `SetClassLongPtr`) and dispose of it.

A much better approach would be to create two brushes that have the same lifetime as the application. It's wasteful to be creating new brushes so frequently. With this approach you would dispose of the brushes at shutdown.

As to the actual implementation of animation, your code is, as you admit, rather poor. `Sleep` is very seldom the solution to any problem and it certainly isn't here. You would be better off with a timer. And as Hans correctly points out, you should handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` to set the background brush. Once you switch to a timer then you don't need to call UpdateWindow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would upvote you but I need 15 reputation.